# Store events for later retrieval

Tags: log-messages

I'm sending out emails on certain events (e.g. new article, or in a cronjob if a certain node hasn't been updated in the last weeks).

Now, I want to track whether these emails get reacted upon. I can easily track the opening of a mail or the click on a link with Google Analytics using ?utm_... query parameters, but can I store inside Drupal that a mail was sent?

For now I'm abusing `watchdog()` and its Views integration, but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [mail tracking](https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_tracking) module. Which is ditto to your description.

Comment: Can I integrate this in already existing reports I built with Views?

Comment: which kind of report you already built?